# Java Springs Connection Pool com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

Folks, I am a java newbie. I am trying to debug an application written by some one else. I see following statements when ever the application hits the database.

```
DEBUG [TP-Processor9] - ooo Using Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@f266c22]

Using Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@1f792416]
```

please note the ID after @ symbol

I want to understand if the code is creating new connection to the DB for each query??

here is my bean configuration :

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      p:jdbcUrl="${db.url}"
      p:user=""
      p:password=""
      p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="25200"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry it doesn't create a new connection for each query. It only creates a new proxy for the JDBC connection. So although the proxy object (instance of NewProxyConnection) is different the connection to DB is reused from the pool.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying. BTW is it ok not to set minPoolSize and maxPoolSize ?

Comment: Default is minPoolSize=3 and maxPoolSize=15, you decide whether is that ok for your app. (based on how many concurrent connection to the DB you want/need to support)